# jQuery Easy Slider Plugin - Restarting Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, easyslider

i`ve got a question about the jQuery Easy Slider 1.7 http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider with numeric navigation.

The problem is, that the automatic animation stops when I click onto a number. Is there a way to make the animation going further even after you clicked a number?

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Realize this is an old thread, but this is what I did to fix it...

1. Around line 160 change this:

   ```
   default:
     t = dir;
     break;
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   default:
     t = parseInt(dir);
     break;
   ```
2. Around line 207 insert this:

   ```
   if(options.numeric){;timeout = setTimeout(function(){animate("next",false);},diff*options.speed+options.pause);};
   ```

Worked for me!